# Access Google App Functions in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sites

I am using google app scripts on google sites. I have created a navigation menu, and I embedded it into the page. I want to get the pageURL() from google scripts and retrieve it in my JavaScript page. I tried using the scriptlet to get the value, but it doesn't execute. Here is what I have so far. How can I get access to values in google app scripts and use them in my JavaScript function?

google script (.gs)

```
 function getPageName(){
    var site = SitesApp.getSite("site.com", "sitename");
    var page = site.getChildren()[0];
    var pageName = page.getUrl().split("/").splice(-1)[0];
    return pageName;
 }
```

javascript file

```
var pageName =  <?!= getPageName()?>; // doesnt execute, need to get page url
if(pageName == linkName){
 // add class here. 
}
```

Since google loads the apps script as an iframe, I tried doing window.location.href, but it doesn't work either. The page name ends up being the name of the google app instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to using scriptlets is to use [`google.script.run` (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

It's pretty easy to use. In your case, it should be like this

**code.gs**

```
function getPageName(){
    var site = SitesApp.getSite("site.com", "sitename");
    var page = site.getChildren()[0];
    var pageName = page.getUrl().split("/").splice(-1)[0];
    return pageName;
 }
```

Javascript File:

```
function onSuccess(receviedPageName)
{
    if(receviedPageName== linkName)
    {
     // add class here. 
    }
}//onSuccess
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getPageName();
```

`withSuccessHandler(function)` is executed if the server-side function returns successfully or `withFailureHandler(function)` is executed if a server side function fails to complete the task it was assigned.

Give it a try :)